# How to upload database backup file to Server?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, localhost, database-backups

We have made a Web based app for School Management System. (Codeigniter, PHP , MYSQL). This app is running in localhost. In app we have provided option to backup database. which is working fine. but the problem is that we don't want that our users download the database because users will see the DB Schema :( instead we want that when user click on Backup we want to upload the database (.sql backup file) to our server. We also tried to upload this file to our gmail account.

I need expert suggestion what we need to do in this case ?

Comment: It's not really a great idea to back up the database from the web application itself, since script runtime restrictions may terminate the backup script before it completes the backup. Backup should be done by DBA / sysadmin on operating system level. They can run scripts from command line (even in regularly scheduled format) that back-up a database.

Comment: The app has only one user that is operator. currently the operator is doing the job of backup in USB device. We want that user backup database but not aware where the file is etc etc also when the user need DB file I have all the backups user did.

Comment: In this case why do not **you** host the application? This would be the professional approach. Relying on php to be able dump the database and send it though the Internet to a remote location within the script runtime restrictions is definitely not something that is professional.

Comment: This is one of the non functional requirements  that " System will run on localhost" because in region where these apps are installed has limited Internet Connection.

Comment: Then you should not have created a web based application. If there is limited Internet connectivity, then how can you expect your app to upload the backup to your server? I'm sorry, but your question does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, allow the backup functions to only super Admin and restrict it from other users. no need to write more code.

Comment: Although we have roles in app which is doing the same thing but the problem is that the app is running locally and has only operator which will do the backup. operator can click on DB Backup file & app will upload the dot sql file to our server. the file wont be downloaded on app machine

Comment: if you are hidding your database from your app operator. than its useless, because he can also visit to localhost/phpmyadmin and can make a backup from there. so working on that thing for security purpose is useless.

Comment: the best thing is that lock the folder where the backup is storing.
you can do it in windows

Comment: localhost/phpmyadmin is password protected.

Comment: you can protect a folder also. the one where backup is stored

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the database backup option from the user. Its better if you give that right only to the super admin.

Comment: The operator is free to backup database to the server by uploading the DB.Super Admin will only use this DB in server when client requested for the latest DB.